# Updating views of Activity or Fragment from a RecyclerView adapter

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, callback, listener, android-adapter

I am trying to update the text in a TextView which is located in the activity to show the total price when an item is deleted from RecyclerView. But how can I update a view which belongs to activity from an adapter?

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Kindly post the entire code with xml files

Comment: that's my xml code @InziKhan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Here is the solution.

1. Create a public interface called `ItemsInteractionListener` which has a method 
   `void onTotalPriceChanged(double newPrice);` inside adapter
2. Create an object of the interface called `mListener` inside the adapter
3. Create a public setter for `mListener`
4. Create a private method called `double getTotalPrice()` which calculates total price from the list.
5. Implement `ItemsInteractionListener` in activity.
   Inside `void onTotalPriceChanged(double newPrice);`, set the new price to the TextView.
6. After creating adapter, set the listener to `this` by calling the setter you created before in step 3.
7. Call `mListener.onTotalPriceChanged(newPrice);` inside adapter whenever a change is made. ie, when adding or deleting items.