# How to update activity views from a fragment recyclerView

Tags: android-activity, android-recyclerview

I have MainActivity which has AppBar (with a "cart" TextView) and FrameLayout (with Fragment which contain a RecyclerView). This RecyclerView has a Button to increase Cart Value count. And I want that count to update Cart value in MainActivity.

I found this one but without full explanation "[Updating views of Activity or Fragment from a RecyclerView adapter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47957822/updating-views-of-activity-or-fragment-from-a-recyclerview-adapter)".

Answer (score 0):

No better solution than this [**`ViewModel`**](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel)

First of all add this dependency in `build.gradle` : `implementation 'android.arch.lifecycle:extensions:1.1.1'`

Your `ViewModel` class will look like this :

```
class MyViewModel: ViewModel() {

    val mCartInfo: MutableLiveData<Int> = MutableLiveData()
    private var cnt = 0

    fun addToCartCounter() {
        //TODO Apply your logic here
        mCartInfo.value = cnt++
    }
}
```

> What is `LiveData`? [See here](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/lifecycle/LiveData.html)

After that you've to initialize your `ViewModel` and observe the changed data, all these things are going to be done in your AppBar's `Activity` :

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        val myViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(MyViewModel::class.java)
        //These will observe any changes happen in ViewModel's MutableLiveData(it'll directly jump inside Observer)
        //Observer is main important thing
        myViewModel.mCartInfo.observe(this, Observer {
            //tvCartCounter is Toolbar's TextView
            tvCartCounter.text = it.toString()
        })
    }
}
```

Get `ViewModel` in your `Fragment` and your button click which calls a ViewModel's method:

```
class BlankFragment : Fragment() {

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        val rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_blank, container, false)

        //Get your Activity's ViewModel
        val myViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(requireActivity()).get(MyViewModel::class.java)
        //Button click
        rootView.btnAddToCart.setOnClickListener {
            //It'll call ViewModel's method
            myViewModel.addToCartCounter()
        }
        return rootView
    }
}
```

> Whenever `addToCartCounter`() calls on your button click it'll add value in `MutableLiveData` soon after it'll triggered your observer.

Comment: Will you please give more elaborate answer, I find it difficult to understand.

Comment: I've edit my answer, please check and inform me. Have a good day:)